# Why does WEBrick use a random port?

Tags: ruby, heroku

I've been following the Heroku getting started guide
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby-o

I'm doing this on a Windows 8 laptop.
I get to the step where I define the Procfile `web: bundle exec ruby web.rb -p $PORT`
Then I run `heroku local`, after which I expect to find the app listening on port 5000.
The output is as follows:

```
$ heroku local
forego | starting web.1 on port 5000
web.1  | [2016-03-22 12:50:29] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
web.1  | [2016-03-22 12:50:29] INFO  ruby 2.1.6 (2015-04-13) [x64-mingw32]
web.1  | [2016-03-22 12:50:29] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=7972 port=64134
web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Mar/2016:12:51:47 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12 0.0166
web.1  | crowne-zbook - - [22/Mar/2016:12:51:47 South Africa Standard Time] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12
web.1  | - -> /
web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Mar/2016:12:51:48 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 420 0.0010
web.1  | crowne-zbook - - [22/Mar/2016:12:51:48 South Africa Standard Time] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 420
web.1  | http://localhost:64134/ -> /favicon.ico
```

I can connect on port 64134, which changes randomly every time.
So my question is, if the documentation says that the app should be available on port 5000,
then why am I seeing `forego` starting on 5000, and `WEBrick` starting on a randomly assigned port number.

Comment: Very strange, but I can't reproduce this on OSX.